# Winforms - Store data based on Gender

Tags: c#, desktop-application

i have created two tables in database...i used a combo box of gender....I want to save male data in male table and female data in female table using windows forms. It is saving data in both the tables but I only need to store it in their respective tables. I want to save data when i select male from gender combo-box in male table and I want to save data when i select female from gender combo-box in female table Any help would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

We suppose this class for your Gender stuff:

```
public class MyGender
{
    public char FemaleOrMale { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You create a new class, per instance:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Object Tag { get; set; }
}
```

After you pouplate this one:

```
List<MyGender> myList = new List<MyGender>();
myList.Add(new MyGender() { FemaleOrMale = 'F', Name = "Stephanie" });
myList.Add(new MyGender() { FemaleOrMale = 'M', Name = "David"});

foreach (MyGender myGender in myList)
{
    myComboBox.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Name = myGender.Name, Value= myGender.FemaleOrMale.ToString(), Tag = myGender });
}
myComboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
myComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

And on selection changed of your combobox, you add per instance this code:

```
private void OnMySelectionChanged()
{
    ComboBoxItem c = (ComboBoxItem)myComboBox.SelectedItem;
    MyGender myGender = (MyGender)c.Tag;
    if(myGender.FemaleOrMale == 'F')
    {
        //Here Female
    }
    else
    {
        //Here Male
    }
}
```